# Overlapping views inside a parent container - React Native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, flexbox

I am building a home project in react-native. While playing with layouts, Views inside a parent container are overlapping. I am using flexbox for designing layout of a form, but unable to get through it. Below is sample code that I have written to explain what issue is.[image]

```
    <View style= {styles.Container}>

      <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'red'}}><Text>RED</Text></View>
      <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'green'}}><Text>GREEN</Text></View>
      <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'blue'}}><Text>BLUE</Text></View>

    </View>

    Container: {
      flex:1,
      backgroundColor:'grey',
      flexDirection:'column',
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the part of your code which you posted nothing is wrong. Perhaps there's something wrong in the parts you didn't provide.

Here's your code in a working example: https://repl.it/Iqek

Comment: I got the fix for error causing with flexbox. Its actually the container where I have set flex:1. After removing the flex:1 property, It worked like a charm.